# In Cypress, how do you test that a property equals one of multiple values?

Tags: javascript, cypress

We are running some tests for a website in Cypress.  In Chrome on Windows, the tests all pass.  On a Mac, however, the widths of some elements are 2px wider than when on Windows.  I understand that this shouldn't be the case, and we'll investigate that separately, but what I would like to know is how do you tests that a value of a test should fall within a range of values?

This is the test that passes in Windows:

```
it('checks Headline container, width & horizontal spacing', () => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=headline]')
    .should('have.css', 'width', '569px')
})
```

This one passes on a Mac.  The only change is the width being `571px` instead of `569px`.

```
it('checks Headline container, width & horizontal spacing', () => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=headline]')
    .should('have.css', 'width', '571px')
})
```

Given that the actual `should()` test is against a string, how would you test that the width is either of two strings instead?  Or an actual range of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `closeTo` for that. It would look like this:

```js
it('checks Headline container, width & horizontal spacing', () => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=headline]')
    .then($element => {
    expect($element.width())
      .closeTo(569, 2)
    })
})
```

The first number of `closeTo` is the wished number, the second number is the margin. For example: If you have `.closeTo(600, 150)` the actual number should be between 450 and 750. So it isn't a very specific check.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found a better answer for my particular use case, though I really do like that there is a `closeTo()` method available.

This is how I solved the problem:

```
  it('checks Headline container, width & horizontal spacing', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=headline]')
      .should('have.css', 'width').and('match', /^(569|571)px/)
  })
```

I used a regular expression to match both the string `569px` and `571px`.

This allows us to keep using `should()` for the tests while ensuring that the value matches one of the two specific sizes we were expecting.

Comment: This is a golden answer for me, albeit for a different scenario! We are testing the font-weight with Cypress, and Electron 61 and Chrome 77 compute it differently. Electron computes it to `bold`, while Chrome computes it to `700`. I want both values to be valid, so I use `.should('have.css', 'font-weight').and('match', /700|bold/)`